# AJAX call for partial views is not working in electron desktop app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, electron

I am new to electron and developing desktop application using .NET core.

I have implemented Partial view and calling through AJAX but AJAX is not working in electron desktop app and it is working fine in browser.

And when I did auto refresh of Partial view, it is working smooth in browser but page is blinking/flickering in electron desktop app. Can anyone help me out from this. Thanks!

I have used this code for auto refresh Partial view:

```js
<script>
      function AutoRefresh( t ) {
           setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
        }
  </script>
```

```html
<body onload="Javascript:AutoRefresh(7000);">
```

This code I have used for Partial Ajax but it is not working in electron desktop app:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

            $("#btnAddMappingKey").click(function() { 
                
                var mappingKey = $("#addMappingKeyForm").serialize();                                                        
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "/Home/GetAccessKey",
                    data: mappingKey,
                    success: function(response) {   
                        console.log("Success");  
                        window.location.reload();                                                                                                                                  
                    }                                                        
                })                    
            });
             
           
        </script>
```

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAccessKey()
        {
            UtilityViewModel utilityView = new UtilityViewModel();
            // Written logic          
            return PartialView("_ShowCompany", utilityView);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, I am not sure if you got the answer yet but this might help others who are wondering about this.

Electron is a desktop development environment based on Node that allows you to use Node and Javascript to create cross-platform desktop application. It does this by running the Chromium browser in a kind of a virtual environment and exposing platform APIs to it.

It does not however run a HTTP server and that's why your Ajax calls (They are http calls) are not working.

What you need to do instead is use Electron-style data communication system> I.e. create a function in javascript at the front-end and fetch data using preload scripts that pull the data from the database or wherever you have it.

Instead of Ajax, you have to create functions in the renderer preload script and expose it to the main world. Check this article

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation